# How to determine the loading time of website

Tags: javascript, web-testing

I am creating a website professionally for a client as my first project and i am using too many libraries for instance velocity.js,jquery,jquery.ui,animate.css and also some image slider plugin for jquery right now i am using the **min** version and all of the files are downloaded in my machine but when i will put the site live will it severely affect the loading time of website or it will be normal.

Comment: You can use one of the performance testing applications online to test it, for example https://www.webpagetest.org/

Comment: Upload your site on to the appropriate domain space and check it out with the Chrome dev tools (Network Tab). The Performance and Audits tabs should help in understanding the perf optimizations that can be made to improve your site. As of Chrome 60, the Coverage option available in Dev Tools helps to narrow down between the used and unused portions of the libraries that you have utilized. Minification will have a significant impact post removal of the unused code.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it up. Test it [Click here](https://tools.pingdom.com/). But the best way is to put it up and test the ping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will severely affect the loading of the page. Chrome comes with developer tools out of the box, and Firebug for Firefox is only a couple of clicks away. That, combined with the RTT time and badnwidth to the site gives you enough information to calculate exactly how slow the first hit page load time.

Assuming that caching is configured correctly, subsequent page transitions should be faster - but even [loading all this javascript from cache and parsing](https://www.dokuwiki.org/template:starterpjax) it will have a big impact on the load time. Note that in the of Dokuwiki, the CMS already handles merging of javascript into a single file.

Using PJax or similar will help with subsequent transitions. Using online repositories for standard libraries does not help with performance. Minimizing the javascript does not give very big wins (since you are already compressing the files on the fly, aren't you?)

There's big wins to be had from defering Javascript loading and stripping/optimizing/merging CSS files.

There are a lot of other things you can do to make your page **render** faster - but space here is too limited.